# Python class global not set

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, global-variables

I have a Python module with two classes, MainWindow (which inherits from QMainWindow) and MyView (which inherits from QGraphicsView). In the MainWindow I have a MyView which should set some variables in the MainWindow class.
So I figured I just put the reference to my MainWindow object into a global variable and let the MyView access it like that. Here's the code:

```
class MyView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyView, self).__init__(parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(MyView, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        print "Mouse Pointer is currently hovering at: ", event.pos()
        global myapp
        print "myapp value is: ", myapp


myapp = None
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    print "myapp assigned, value is: ", myapp
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After clicking on the MyView the program output is this:

```
$ ./main.py 
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
myapp assigned, value is:  <__main__.MainWindow object at 0x7fc29e1ed640>
Mouse Pointer is currently hovering at:  PyQt4.QtCore.QPoint(172, 132)
myapp value is:  None
```

Why is this? I'm not setting "myapp" to a different value, in the posted code are all occurcences of it.

Comment: you have `parent` in `MyView` to access `MainWindow`

Comment: The example code is very misleading, because it does not produce the stated output. I would guess that the real reason your code doesn't work is because you are trying to import from the main script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PyQt, you can also use the `parent()` method.

If you define `MyView` with a parent `MainWindow`:

```
 # either in __main__
 myapp = MainWindow()
 myview= MyView(myapp)

 # or in the class MainWindow
 self.myView=MyView(self)
```

Then `myview.parent()` allows you to access `myapp`

```
>>> print(myView.parent())
<__main__.MainWindow object at 0x7f02869b2678>
```

Comment: Luckily for me, Qt Designer makes the object instantiation, and it does  the right thing in my case. The access through the parent() worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not lloking for the `global` keyword here. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python) to see a nice explanation about the `global` keyword.

In this case you simply need to access the global `myapp` created in the main module, like so:

```
globals()['myapp']
```

Comment: "globals()['myapp']" also returns "None" inside the MyView class.